# Haxe: Return value of field

Tags: function, variables, return, field, haxe

For some reason, I can't modify the value of a field in Haxe. Of course, this doesn't seem to be affecting all of my fields, just this one. Here's (what I'm pretty sure is) the applicable code.  First, in the parent class:

```
class TopMenu extends Sprite 
{
    public function new() 
    {
        super();
        init();
    }
    private function init() 
    {
        var tempField:BitmappedTextField = new BitmappedTextField( "File", 100, false );
        trace( tempField.textWidth );
    }
}
```

Then, in the child class:

```
class BitmappedTextField extends Sprite
{
    private var _fieldText:String;
    private var _fieldWidth:Int;
    private var _addToStage:Bool;
    public var textWidth:Int;
    public function new( thisText:String, thisWidth:Int = 100, adTStg:Bool = true ) 
    {
        super();
        _fieldText = thisText;
        _fieldWidth = thisWidth;
        _addToStage = adTStg;
        textWidth = 55;
        init();
    }
    public function init()
    {
        textWidth = 777;
    }
}
```

I would expect the `trace` statement to return `777`, but instead it will always return `55`. In fact, no matter what I do, I can't seem to modify a field outside of the constructor class and then retrieve that value via the parent class. There's something horribly simple I must be missing, but I just can't figure it out. Maybe it has to do with the way Haxe uses getters and setters? Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I cant reproduce your problem however and you are missing a ; and a super call.

Try this code.

```
package;

import nme.display.Sprite;
import nme.display.MovieClip;

class HelloWorld extends MovieClip
{
        public function new( )
        {
            super();
            var tempField:BitmappedTextField = new BitmappedTextField();
            trace( tempField.textWidth );
        }
}

class BitmappedTextField extends Sprite
{
        public var textWidth:Int;

        public function new( )
        {
            super();
            textWidth = 55;
            init( );
        }

        public function init( )
        {
            textWidth = 777; 
        }
}
```

Comment: This code properly returns 777 in the trace. Why did you have HelloWorld extend MovieClip? I only ask because in my case, the parent and child class both extend Sprite, and I'm wondering if that might be a source of my problems. I'll add more code in my question; I was trying to keep it brief.

Comment: Well, the original code was just to show what kind of problem I was having; the revised code in the question is much more representative of my actual program. I'm still having the same problem, though. What bloat does Sprite have? Is there somewhere I could read more about that? I'm just wondering, as I'd assumed Sprite would be lighter on resources than MovieClip.

Comment: Well choosing what to extend for your initial stage class is usually a non issue and actually MovieClip extends Sprite so I was wrong about that. Read about it in the classes themselves like I just corrected myself. An IDE with Goto Definition like intellij idea makes that easier. You might find it helpful to look at some articles about the concept of a display list http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/as3-101the-display-list/ this talks about the stage a little more http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/display_list_programming_as3.html

Comment: Thanks for the references, I'll be sure to take a look at them. I wish I understood why I was having a problem with such a simple task as retrieving a value from a child object... something must be really broken somewhere in my code.

Comment: Its probably just a simple wrong placement of code. Have you used a debugger with breakpoints before? this is the kind of thing where it helps greatly to see the order of whats going on. Flash Develop IDE has a free debugger for haxe with flash.

Comment: I've done so very many trace statements, etc. but there may be stuff in the IDE I haven't used yet, so I'll take a look at that. I know that the value of the variable doesn't ever get changed, except in the new() function.  Any attempt to change it anywhere else never happens, almost like the code is making it's own instance variables for each function, but even with a `this.` before the variable, it still doesn't work.

Comment: The Haxe new() function you mention is the class constructor similar to how as3 uses the class name as it's constructor, so its the first thing that's run when creating a new instance of a class. Learning how the the debugger and how the breakpoints work etc is an invaluable tool for development.